# How to trim the white space before figure caption?

Tags: graphics, ieeetran

I'm using

```
\documentclass[journal,transmag]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
%
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0pt}
\begin{figure*}[!t]
\centering
\scalebox{.9}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig}}
\caption{result}
\end{figure*}
%
\end{document}
```

and I'm inserting a ".pdf" figure. The problem is that I have a big white space after the figure and before the caption. In generating the ".pdf" file I've tried to minimize the white space as much as I could but when uploading in Latex there appears to be a bis white empty space. Can I trim this in Latex?

Thank you.

Comment: BTW, No need to scale twice: `\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{fig}` without the additional `\scalebox` will do.

Comment: If I understand your issue correctly, there's a lot of unwanted whitespace between the graphic and the caption. Have you checked if the pdf image file maybe contains whitespace at its bottom edge?

Comment: Never add the `pdftex` (or `dvips`) option to `graphicx`.

Answer (score 5):

### Trimming of PDF images

The program `pdfcrop` calls ghostscript to calculate the visible area of the
image and writes a PDF file with the new bounding box without the white space
margins:

```
pdfcrop fig.pdf
```

This writes `fig-crop.pdf`. Also a different output file name can be specified, see pdfcrop's options.

Then the cropped image is inserted in LaTeX:

```
\includegraphics{fig-crop}
```

Alternatively options `trim` or `viewport` of `\includegraphics` can be used
to reduce the margins. But the margins have to be measured for specifying the right arguments for `trim` or `viewport`, see [LaTeX's graphics guide](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/graphics/grfguide.pdf).

### Change of default spacing above figure captions

The class `IEEEtran` has hooks: for setting the space between the figure and its caption and a table caption and its table

```
\def\@IEEEfigurecaptionsepspace{\vskip\abovecaptionskip\relax}%
\def\@IEEEtablecaptionsepspace{\vskip\abovecaptionskip\relax}%
```

They can be redefined to reduce the space:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@IEEEfigurecaptionsepspace}{%
  \vskip.5\abovecaptionskip\relax
}%
\makeatother
```

Or

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@IEEEfigurecaptionspace}{}
\makeatother
```

But beware, the journal might want to have the original space.

Comment: I don't want to change the default spacing. My problem is due to my figure itself.

Comment: Thanks Heiko. I'm using an online Tex editor/compiler. How can I use pdfcrop there?

Comment: @Elnaz You are also creating the image online? Can't you use pdfcrop locally and upload the cropped image?

Comment: The problem is that my miktex and texmaker are not working. Something is wrong with their installation.

Comment: Could you include a reference of how to install pdfcrop on Windows 7?

Comment: @Elnaz Try to fix MiKTeX or reinstall it. `pdfcrop` uses pdfTeX (or LuaTeX or XeTeX) to rewrite the PDF file.

Comment: I installed pdfcrop from the Package Manager (Admin) and then wrote a simple script: `\documentclass[journal,transmag]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{pdfcrop}
\begin{document}
pdfcrop fig1.pdf
\end{document}`, but I get "pdfcrop.sty not found" error. Am I doing it right?

Comment: @Elnaz pdfcrop is a program, not a LaTeX package.

Comment: it was in the list in package manager within different packages. I haven't been able to find an inclusive document instructions of how to install and work with pdfcrop. Can you direct me to one?

Comment: @Elnaz [CTAN entry](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop), [README](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/pdfcrop/README), and running `pdfcrop --help` on the command line gives an option summary.

Comment: thanks. What is the difference btw pdfcrop and those user-interface pdf softwares that offer cropping?

Comment: @Elnaz A comment is hardly appropriate to compare one program with an infinite set of other unknown programs. If you are interested in the matter, check the programs out and compare them (topic, license, features, operating system, methods, implementation, advantages, drawbacks, ...)

Comment: I just meant to compare as a user, because it seems that everyone uses pdfcrop I was wondering if there's a reason, for example, do they lower the pdf quality?

Comment: I mean when we crop a part of an image and lay it down on the same size paper, that should lower the quality. Does this happen and with which software?

Comment: @Elnaz pdfcrop lets ghostscript calculate the image size and rewrites the PDF file via pdfTeX (or LuaTeX or XeTeX) to a new PDF file with a smaller MediaBox/CropBox entries. The page description does not change in this process. If the PDF contains vector data, then it can be scaled without loss of quality. In case of bitmap data, the resolution is lowered, if the image is up-scaled. But the image data are not change either.